# syncing texlive installationon across linux computers

Tags: texlive

on my two computers, one laptop one desktop, I keep my home directories synced. My texlive installation resides in my home directory and could thus be synced as well, currently it is excluded. Right now e.g. updates need to be applied twice, once on every machine. Syncing the texlive installation directory would make the second update obsolete.

Is there a downside or even a definitive reason against syncing the texlive installation directory? Texlive is not installed via package manager.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure this question is specific to TexLive, and answers could diverges depending if you're using the same OS on both systems or not, and relatively to particular set-ups. Did you try to digest [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6344/101324) or [this one](http://superuser.com/q/31512/446943)? Would the propagation of the updates be uni-directional (i.e., you always perform the update on the same computer, and then you propagate it to the other)?

Comment: Same OS on both machines with roughly the same OS updates. I think I have home directory syncing figured out, at least I hope. Updates to home directories and texlive would be bidirectional, depending on which machine gets updated first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running the same os-arch combination on both machines, then syncing is fine. The only difference I see that could appear is in the luatex fontcache that takes into account also system fonts. These system fonts might disagree, and thus the cache be outdated. Other than that I don't see a reason why syncing could pose any problem.

In fact, although it is not syncing, I have used TeX Live mounted via nfs in my former department with several different arch-os combinations, all without a problem. That means that syncing should work in the same way.

Comment: I've also copied an installation from one Linux box to another (different distros, but same arch) to save starting installation from scratch on the second machine. (And get local matched, too.)